# How to create my own vector iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

So I have some specific vector

```
vector< MyType >
```

And I want to iterate through this vector in a specific way. I decided to make my own vector iterator, derived from vector< MyType >::const_iterator. This «specific way» is the way how indexes should change through the iteration and it depends on two initial values, so I wrote something like this:

```
class MyVectorIterator: public vector< MyType >::const_iterator
{
     MyVectorIterator(unsigned int, bool);
     ...
}
```

But how should I determine the start index and what operators and methods should I overload?

Comment: How do you know `vector< MyType >::const_iterator` is a class type? It could just be a `MyType const *`. In other words, what you're trying to do is not a good idea. Write functions that manipulate the `vector::(const_)iterator` how you want, instead of trying to encapsulate that logic within the custom iterator type.

Comment: I would **HIGHLY** suggest looking through [Boost.iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) before doing anything like this.

Comment: Specifically, you can do this with a few lines using [`boost::iterator_adaptor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_adaptor.html)

Comment: You could start with [`std::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator).